# phpMyAdmin mbstring is missing

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I try `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gives me the following message - the other file of PHP are working correctly on `localhost`...

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>   The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: No problem! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!